# Long-term side effects of anti-covid vaccines

Tags: vaccination, clinical-study

I am interested in statistical procedures and study designs used to determine the absence/acceptability of long-term side effects of the anti-covid vaccines. Given that these vaccines were created and approved within a short period of time (less than a year), it seems that the studies using conventional survival analysis are of little value (i.e., we cannot make predictions for decades ahead). I assume that one relies on the similarity with other, well-tested vaccines.

What are the statistical procedures for evaluating long-term side effects in such cases?

**Background:**

- I have posted earlier a [similar question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/97370) in the biology community, which evolved through the discussions with the members of that community. I do not repost it in its entirety, as it may bias the answers in a wrong direction.
- I come from a quantitative field and have some experience in biostatistics, so I am looking for a serious answer or references to the relevant literature.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Medical Sciences. I can't seem to find an actual question in your post. I see the far more detailed question you have in Biology, but that's a different question with more detail? Questions need to be self-sufficient and not depend on outside links, so could you please clarify your question and add the level of detail your other question has?

Comment: @CareyGregory thank you for your input/suggestions. I adjusted my question to accomodate them.